# How can I download create-react-native-app files manually?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I trying to create a react native project, but always it gives me an download error (the create-react-native-app is installed), I try:

```
create-react-native-app Test
```

But always in the file `ngrok-2.3.0.tgz` I get an error. I downloaded the file manually, but I don't know where it goes, I try to put in AppData/Local/Temp (shown in the error text), but when running the command again, it overwrite the file and try to download it over again. Where are the react-native files to which I can put `ngrok-2.3.0.tgz` manually?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this with an LTS (Long Term Support) version of Node? (i.e. 6 or 8)?

Comment: @MattHolland, no, what's the difference? You think this can solve my problem?

Comment: I think it's worth a try! Odd numbered versions of Node (And even numbered versions of NPM) are more "experimental", the even number releases are intended to be more stable. One more thing you can try is `npm cache clean` to clear out your module cache, in case you have somehow downloaded a "bad" version of that module.

Comment: @MattHolland, I tried `npm cache clean`, download all again, and in the same file I get an error, the file have 60mb, sometimes download only 10mb, sometimes 16mb, but never full. I downloaded an old version of npm (because `create-react-native-app` don't work in npm v5+ or something like that), they should already be stable, no?

Answer (score 1):

The registry had some issues a few days ago resulting in the same error.

Take a look https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19816

- You can also try doing things with yarn
- Offline packages can be done with `yarn link ngrok` which will indicate yarn/npm to get the local copy of ngrok.

Comment: `An unexpected error occurred: "No registered module found called \"ngrok\"
.".` anyway, I resolve this with `npm install react-native` instead `npm instal create-react-native-app`, but I have a question, in any project creation the React needs to download all the project files? My network is very bad, why it can't download just one time?

Comment: No, react-native is different as it doesn't use EXPO (which is trying to download ngrok). if the issue with internet is a constant you might want to get a virtual desktop and use it with RDP :)  - there is a free one https://aws.amazon.com/windows/products/ec2/server2012r2/